# Backbone doesn't remove View when Model removed

Tags: backbone.js

There's a remove method on EventView. When I click on the remove button, the Event (Model) should be removed so as the EventView.

With the following code, I can remove the Model from mongodb by clicking on the remove button. But the Model View won't remove itself until I refresh the page.

I am using express, EJS and mongodb for this demo.

**app.js** // with express routes settings

```
events.init = function(req, res) {  res.render('index') };

events.all = function(req, res) {
    db.event.find({}, function(err, event) {
        if (err) return;
        res.json(event);
    });
}

events.delete = function (req, res) {
    var Id = db.ObjectId(req.params.id);
    db.event.remove({
        "_id": Id
    });
}

app.get('/', events.init);
app.get('/events', events.all);
app.del('/events/:id', events.delete);
```

**client.js** // Backbone Model, Collection and View setup

```
var Event = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id"
});

var EventCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Event,
    url: "/events"
});

var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click .remove": "remove"
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    },

    remove: function (e) {
        this.model.destroy();
    },

    render: function () {
        var html = new EJS({url: '/partials/event-field.ejs'}).render(this.model);
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this
    }   

});


var EventCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function () {

        this.collection.each(function(event){
            var eventView = new EventView({ model: event });
            this.$el.append(eventView.render().$el);
        }, this);

        return this
    }   
});
```

**init.js** // Called on page load

```
$(function () { 

    var collection = new EventCollection();
    collection.fetch({
        success: function(data){
            var collectionView = new EventCollectionView({ collection: data})
            $('.upcoming .list-group').append(collectionView.render().$el);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't see your server returning any success response for delete route. Is the delete request getting `200` status back?

Comment: When I click the remove button. An error logged out DELETE http://localhost:3000/events/573e930f81147249b7ed66f8 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. But I am really confused, if it's not running properly how come that model got deleted in mongodb?

Comment: The request reaches the server, it gets deleted from db. You need to respond back saying the operation was successful right? How does the client know it worked? Since the server doesn't respond back at all it says CONNECTION_REFUSED. Your answer is not a reliable way because even if some error occurs in backend your method will work and model view will be removed from client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I found out how to make it work.

I renamed the remove method to destroy and changed the destroy method like so.

```
events: {
    "click .remove": "destroy"
},

initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.destroy);
},

destroy: function () {
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
    this.model.destroy();

},
```